# EXCEL- Editing Excel's before copying to a new sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have between 800 excels files that I need to transfer over to one sheet but before the transfer, I need to add a column ("A:A") and copy one cell value (before column added ("C1") after column ("D1")) and use column ("C:C") to get the range it would need to be pasted in column("A:A")

[image: Example of the output needed]

I have done the code already but struggling to add this on. If anyone can help that would be amazing.

```
Sub LoopThrough()

Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String
Dim sh As Worksheet, MasterRange As Range, TempWB As Workbook, TempSH As Worksheet, TempRng As Range, TempRow As Range
Dim NewMasterLine As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

StartTime = Timer

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Change address to suite
MyDir = "C:\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xls")
ChDir MyDir

' The following lines will put excel in a state similar to "frozen" mode. This will increase the code performance, as CPU will solely focus on performing
' the operations required by the code and not on showing the changes happening on excel
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim x As Long

x = 0

' Here starts the loop related to the files in folder
Do While MyFile <> ""
  'TempWB is a Worksheet object - will be the importing worksheet. TempRng is the used range in sheet 1 of the workbook
  Set TempWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False, Password:=CalcPassword(MyFile))
  Columns(1).Insert
  Range("c2").Copy Range("A4:A10000")
  Set TempSH = TempWB.Worksheets(1)
  Set TempRng = TempSH.Range("A1:DB" & TempSH.Range("A" & TempSH.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

---

```
  TempRng.Range("A:A").Insert ' This is where I tried to add in the extra column
  TempRng.Range("A1").Value = TempRng.Range("D1").Value ' Tried doing this as a test but still pasted as if no changes had been made????
```

---

```
  'NewMasterLine is the last used row (+1) of the Master Workbook (It is basically where the new rows will start to be imported)
  NewMasterLine = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  If NewMasterLine > 1 Then NewMasterLine = NewMasterLine + 1
  
  'This will loop through all the rows of the range to be imported, checking the first column.
  ' If the value in the second column is work-xne-ams, will import the single row in the master workbook
  For Each TempRow In TempRng.Rows
      If Left(TempRow.Cells(1, 2).Value, 5) = "SHIFT" Or TempRow.Row < 4 Then
    'If TempRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = "SHIFT--1" Or TempRow.Row < 4 Then
      Set MasterRange = sh.Range("A" & NewMasterLine & ":DA" & NewMasterLine)
      MasterRange.Value = TempRow.Value
      NewMasterLine = NewMasterLine + 1
    End If
  Next
  
  TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
  MyFile = Dir()
  
  x = x + 1

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PWD").Range("H2") = x
  
Loop

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "An error occurred." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Last file that was attempted to be opened: " & MyFile & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
     MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

     MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Function CalcPassword(FileName As String) As String
  CalcPassword = ""
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim TheFile As String: TheFile = Split(Split(FileName, "\")(UBound(Split(FileName, "\"))), ".")(0)
  Dim PWD As Range: Set PWD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PWD").ListObjects("PWD").DataBodyRange
  CalcPassword = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TheFile, PWD, 5, False)
End Function
```

Comment: So you want the **value** of D1 in that new column inserted? Or you want to copy **whole cell** (value, format, etc.) into that new column inserted?

Comment: Is the picture you show us what you need? If yes, I cannot understand from your question what the picture shows ("use column ("C:C") to get the range it would need to be pasted in column("A:A")... If not, why do you show it to us?

Comment: If you really need help, I would suggest you to edit your question and place two pictures. One showing the sheet as it is and the second one as you want. Then, if your big code works as you need, except a column inserting and some data to populate it (only you know what and where from), it will also be good to show us only that code part. If the whole code does not do what you need, it will also be good to reformulate the question and tell us what does not go as you want...

Comment: Still alive? Do you really need help? I spent some time looking on your code, even if I shouldn't, seeing your pseudo interest in solving the problem and independent of what you really need it should be good to make the next changes. You firstly must comment `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`. This line only does not let you seeing where an error exists. You will uncomment it only after you debugged the code. Then, do you need to insert a column, as you say, or only a column slice having the same number of rows as the range you used like object?

Comment: If you want inserting a column (like it looks to be most probable), you should use the sheet object instead of the range. `TempsSh.Range("A:A").Insert`...

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru sorry for the late reply, for some reason, I am not getting notifications for when someone comments on my question. 

D1 would need to auto-populate the full column ("A:A") until it matched the bottom row of Column C.

Comment: Also @FaneDuru for spending time on the code it really is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information as I haven't a clue what I am doing wrong.